# How to kill NSWindow properly?

Tags: macos, nswindow, lifetime, appkit, reference-counting

Recently, I discovered surprising behavior of `NSWindow`. It doesn't die while it is displayed on screen regardless of existence of reference to it.

```
import Foundation
import AppKit

final class W1: NSWindow {
    deinit {
        print("W1.deinit")
    }
}

print("start")
autoreleasepool {
    var w1:W1? = W1()
    w1?.setFrame(NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100), display: true)
    w1?.orderFront(nil)
    w1 = nil
}
print("finish")
RunLoop.main.run()
```

Code above prints `start` and `finish` but no `W1.deinit`.

I tested this on these platforms.

- Xcode 10 on Mojave
- Xcode 11 GM (first) on Catalina Beta

And confirmed same result on both platforms.

---

Here are my questions.

- Why `NSWindow` don't die?
- How am I supposed to manage `NSWindow`?
- How to kill it properly?

As last reference to `NSWindow` has been removed, it is supposed to die immediately. But it doesn't.

If it do not die, it means there's another "hidden" reference to it or AppKit have "special" behavior on windows. What's the reason?

---

Window dies if I `close()` it before removing last reference to it. But I am not sure whether this is really proper/designed way to kill it as it's out of Cocoa/Swift lifetime management rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using macOS 10.15 Catalina Beta so this issue could be only the problem of this beta release.

---

Just calling `close()` can make several issues.
If your `NSWindow` instance haven't been open, calling `close()` causes an exception of sending `release` message to deallocated object. You can check it with Zombies-on.

See this example. This works with no problem.

```
final class TestWindow: NSWindow {
    deinit { print("TestWindow.deinit!") }
}
var w: NSWindow? = TestWindow()
w?.setFrame(NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100), display: true)
w?.orderFront(nil)
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1), execute: {
    w?.close()
    w = nil
})
RunLoop.main.run()

// Okay.
TestWindow.deinit!
```

But if you haven't open your window, this causes an `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`.

```
var w: NSWindow? = TestWindow()
w?.setFrame(NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100), display: true)
// w?.orderFront(nil)
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1), execute: {
    w?.close()
    w = nil
})
RunLoop.main.run()

// An exception!
TestWindow.deinit!
2019-09-21 14:08:06.192106+0700 NSWindowLifetime1[73485:5304415] *** -[NSWindowLifetime1.TestWindow release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1005aafc0
```

Calling `setIsVisible(false)` or `orderOut(nil)` doesn't let window to be released.

```
var w: NSWindow? = TestWindow()
w?.setFrame(NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100), display: true)
w?.orderFront(nil)
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1), execute: {
    w?.orderOut(nil)
    w?.setIsVisible(false)
    w = nil
})
RunLoop.main.run()

// Window disppears but doesn't get released.

var w: NSWindow? = TestWindow()
w?.setFrame(NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100), display: true)
//w?.setIsVisible(true)
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1), execute: {
    w?.setIsVisible(false)
    w = nil
})
RunLoop.main.run()
// Works. No exception.
```

Calling `close()` is the only working solution so far I could find.

```
var w: NSWindow? = TestWindow()
w?.setFrame(NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100), display: true)
w?.orderFront(nil)
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1), execute: {
    w?.close()
    w = nil
})
RunLoop.main.run()

// Okay.
TestWindow.deinit!
```

But this throws an exception if the window hasn't been open.

```
var w: NSWindow? = TestWindow()
w?.setFrame(NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100), display: true)
//w?.orderFront(nil)
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1), execute: {
    w?.close()
    w = nil
})
RunLoop.main.run()


TestWindow.deinit!
2019-09-21 14:26:06.410662+0700 NSWindowLifetime1[73801:5322002] *** -[NSWindowLifetime1.TestWindow release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1005c2c80
```

---

More interestingly, you can set window hidden by calling `setIsVisible(false)`, but this doesn't make window get released if it once became visible.

```
var w: NSWindow? = TestWindow()
w?.setFrame(NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100), display: true)
w?.setIsVisible(true)
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1), execute: {
    w?.setIsVisible(false)
    w = nil
})
RunLoop.main.run()

// No release.
```

And as it's been invisible, you cannot call `close()` conditionally by visibility check.

---

IMO there's no simple and reliable way to close window safely.

- If you don't close window, it'll be leaked until app process dies.
- If you just close window unconditionally, it can throw an exception if the window hasn't been visible.

So far the best way to deal with this would be

- Always open the window if you once made it.
- Always close it.

Just don't make any hidden window that never be open.

If you have to keep it hidden at first just call `orderFront` and `orderOur` immediately right after window creation to make it ordered once without presenting.

```
var w: NSWindow? = TestWindow()
w?.setFrame(NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100), display: true)
w?.orderFront(nil)
w?.orderOut(nil)
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1), execute: {
    w?.close()
    w = nil
})
RunLoop.main.run()
```

---

This could be a problem limited to beta release. I am using these beta releases.

- macOS 10.15 Catalina Beta
- Xcode 11 GM 2

Comment: `close()` causes crash but `setIsVisible(false)` works for me 

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't violate the Cocoa/Swift lifetime management rules. The lifetime management rules are always about local correctness. You ensure the relevant part of your code (a single function/method, a single class, etc.) does the right thing and other code (in your own project, in system libraries, in third-party libraries, etc.) is expected to do the right thing for its needs. The right thing often includes maintaining a strong reference, possibly beyond the point where your code keeps one.

For example, Cocoa *could* put each window that's shown into an `Array` of on-screen windows and remove it when it's closed. (I don't know if it does that, but it's perfectly valid.)

In any case, yes, calling `close()` is correct. (There are other ways, such as `performClose()`, or the `close()` method of `NSWindowController`.)

Comment: I didn't know about existence of other owners of `NSWindow`, but if it potentially can have other owners, I think I have to know the details to manage `NSWindow` properly. Do you know any document mentioning about potential other owners?

Comment: There is, in general, no documentation about potential owners of any object. Part of what I mean by "the rules are local" is that you're not supposed to care. You simply handle your end correctly and you don't need to know or care about the "global" situation. You must never assume that clearing your strong references means an object is deallocated. What difficulty in managing an `NSWindow` properly arises from not knowing what other owners there might be?

Comment: I just wanted RAII-like automatic/deterministic lifetime. And it seems it was just a fantasy in shared ownership system. There are many concerns, but it's gonna be too long to discuss if you don't agree on benefits of RAII. Thanks anyway.

Comment: From the [Appkit release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKit/index.html) "If your application is linked on macOS 10.13 SDK or later, NSWindows that are ordered-in will be strongly referenced by AppKit, until they are explicitly ordered-out or closed (not including hide or minimize operations). This means that, generally, an on-screen window will not be deallocated (and close/order-out as a side-effect of deallocation).".

Answer (score 2):

> Why NSWindow don't die?

Why would it? You didn't close it.

> How am I supposed to manage NSWindow?

By closing it when you want it to close, and releasing any strong references you have to it when you don't care about it any more. These two events are not equivalent. Maintaining a strong reference means "I care about this object." Calling close means "I want this window to close." Do the thing you mean.

> How to kill it properly?

Same.

Comment: I expected I am the sole owner of a `NSWindow` object as I didn't know existence of any other owner. I couldn't find mention about other owner in documentation of `NSWindow`, therefore I didn't expect to have any.

Comment: Yeah it's shared ownership. Do you know any document mentioning about other owners of `NSWindow`?